# Struggling with inequality involving a bunch of binomial coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I want to find a lower bound on $n$, i.e. isolate $n$, or more realisticly, approximate $n$ that satisfies the following :

$$
{n \choose k}\left( 1 - \frac{{n \choose \frac{n-1}{2} - k}}{{n \choose \frac{n - 1}{2}}} \right)^{n - k} < 1
$$

This would be useful for some probabilistic argument.
But I get stuck easily.  The inequalities $(\frac{n}{k})^k \leq {n \choose k} \leq (\frac{en}{k})^k$ and $(1 - x)^k \leq e^{-xk}$ would surely prove useful here...

Also, I know that 
the inequality ${n \choose k}\left( 1 - 2^{- k}\right)^{n - k} < 1$ is satisfied when $n > k^2 2^k (\ln(2) + 1)$.  I would expect the above to have a lower bound, something like $n > k 2^k (\ln(2) + 1)$ maybe.  But how can I even verify that ?

Comment: My rough estimations yield $n\ge\approx k^2$,  but I have to look at them more accurately. I hope to present them soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Start with a straightforward approach. Assume $n\gg k$. Then

$$A(n)\equiv \frac{{n \choose \frac{n-1}{2} - k}}{{n \choose \frac{n - 1}{2}}}=$$
$$\frac{\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{n-1}{2}-k\right)! \left(\frac{n+1}{2}+k\right)!}=$$
$$\frac{\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{n-1}{2}-1\right)\cdots \left(\frac{n-1}{2}-k+1\right)}
{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}+k\right) \left(\frac{n+1}{2}+k-1\right)\cdots \left(\frac{n+1}{2}+1\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\frac{n^k}{2^k}-\frac{n^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} in^{k-1}+O(n^{k-2})}{\frac{n^k}{2^k}+O(n^{k-1})}=$$
$$1-k(k-1)n^{-1}+O(n^{-2}).$$

Then

$$1>{n \choose k}^{\frac{1}{n-k}}(1-A(n))=$$ 
$$\left(\frac{n^k}{k!}+O(n^{k-1})\right)^{\frac{1}{n-k}} (k(k-1)n^{-1}+O(n^{-2}))=$$
$$\left(1+o(1)\right)(k(k-1)n^{-1}+O(n^{-2}))=$$
$$k(k-1)n^{-1}+o(n^{-1}).$$

So we can approximate $n$ as $k^2$. But if $n\sim k^2$ then our estimation for $A(n)$ seems to be not good, so we have to adjust it.

Comment: That sounds right.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ManuelLafond Thanks. But, I have to recall that the answer is not finished, because the estimation for $A(n)$  has to be adjusted, so I expect the final bound in the best case be like $k^{2+\varepsilon}$ or $k^2\ln k$.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  That's good enough for my purposes since I was already assuming $n > 2^k$ (though I didn't mention it).

Comment: @ManuelLafond I think there is something strange with my arguments. They are based on the initial assumption $n\gg k$, and, in fact, are used to show that $A(n)<1$ , which is always true. :-) So I’ll try to use more rigorous arguments. Are you interested in possible $n\le 2^k$ or this assumption is senseless in the context of your problem?

Comment: Well, inspired by your line of reasoning, I approximated $A(n) \geq \left( \frac{(n - 1)/2 - k}{(n + 1)/2 + k} \right)^k$, which leads me to $n > k^2$ working - if I didn't make any mistake.  But indeed, the fact that the expression is smaller than one for some value $n < 2^k$ just means that I made a mistake in establishing my probabilities...it should not be the case.  So thanks for helping me clear that up !